# Searching for name in a string PHP

Tags: php, string, search

I have a string in php which I am trying to get the name from.

the string output is "| name=thomas | country=usa " etc

I want to be able to get the name "thomas" into a php variable.

Note: the data is dynamic so Im trying to find a way to search without hardcoding thomas.

Heres my code:

```
    $people= ($_GET['people']);

preg_match_all('/name="([^"]+)"/mi', $people, $matches);

var_dump ($matches[1]);
```

I receive an array to string conversion error in php.

Comment: Is this the code that produces the string in question? In that case, how did you get `$matches[1]` to output a *string*? It should output an array instead

Comment: why you used double quotes in the pattern? also, please tell us exactly how your $_GET['people'] look like? is that true always? `"| name=thomas | country=usa "`

Answer (score 2):

Use this regular expression

```
<?php
$str='| name=thomas | country=usa ';
preg_match_all('/=(.*?) /', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1][0]);  //"prints" thomas
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I take it that this searches for '=' and anything after until a space? :P

Answer (score 0):

```
function yourSearch($haystack) {
    $string= 'Enter value to search for';
    return(strpos($mystack, $string)); // or stripos() if you want case-insensitive searching.
}

$matches = array_filter($your_array, 'yourSearch');
```